# File reading /Serial communication issue

Tags: python, c++, serial-port

i have 2 programs, one reading data, and putting it into a file, the other reads that file and sends the data via serial.
both program runs parallel, and both of them is an infinite loop with a 200ms delay.
they puts/reads  7 characters in/from the file (6, but " " does not count).

the one which write the file works good, but the sender gets really slow after the 165th loop. always at 165, it only sends one character/second, so it takes the program 6 seconds to send the array.

this is in the file:

```
s5 1038
```

1. an 's' character, it has a function.
2. then one number from 1-9.

   3-4-5-6-7 space (" ") which c filereader dont count, then 4 number, 0000-9999.

the file always have only one line.

the senders loop:

```
while(SP->IsConnected()) //see if the usb connection is on.
    {
        fstream file;
        file.open("c:/Python27/beki.txt");
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            file >> incomingData[i];  //puts the read data from the file into an array, i did this but now i  dont know how this works, but it works.
            cout << incomingData[i];
        }
        file.close();
        cout <<szam << "\n";
        SP->WriteData(incomingData,dataLength);

        szam++; //counting, thats why i know its always slows at 166.
        Sleep(200);

    }
```

it did the same in python. dont know if there's a limit or something. please help.